# shape of pandas dataframe to 3d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to convert pandas dataframe to 3d array, but cannot get the real shape of the 3d array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df['a'][3:]=1
df['a'][:3]=2
a3d = np.array(list(df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
a3d.shape
(2,)
```

But, when I set as this, I can get the shape

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df['a'][2:]=1
df['a'][:2]=2
a3d = np.array(list(df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
a3d.shape
(2,2,5)
```

Is there some thing wrong with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the `dtype`? or the array itself (which isn't that big)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code, it's because in the first case, you don't have a 3d array. By definition of an [N-d array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) (here 3d), first two lines explain that each dimension must **have the same size**. In the first case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df['a'][3:]=1
df['a'][:3]=2
a3d = np.array(list(df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
```

You have a 1-d array of size 2 (it's what `a3d.shape` shows you) which contains 2-d array of shape (1,5) and (3,5)

```
a3d[0].shape
Out[173]: (1, 5)
a3d[1].shape
Out[174]: (3, 5)
```

so both elements in the first dimension of what you call `a3d` does not have the same size, and can't be considered as other dimensions of this `ndarray`.

While in the second case,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df['a'][2:]=1
df['a'][:2]=2
a3d = np.array(list(df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))

a3d[0].shape
Out[176]: (2, 5)
a3d[1].shape
Out[177]: (2, 5)
```

both elements of your first dimension have the same size, so `a3d` is a 3-d array.